# Angular - Declare variable within component template

Tags: angular

I have to disable/enable a button based on the value from a textbox.

This is how I do it currently

```
<input [(ngModel)]="confirmationText" type='text'>
<button [disabled]="confirmationText != 'yes'">Delete</button>
```

**The problem:** This works, but I have to declare `confirmationText` in my component.ts file and I use it **only** in the template, So I'm looking for a way to declare it within the component's template so that I can keep my component class clean.

#### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zx5aa7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) to achieve what you want. Please note that the `ngModel` directive must be set on the input element in order to make it work.

```
<input #textInput type="text" ngModel>
<button [disabled]="textInput.value !== 'yes'">Delete</button>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6gwo3) for a demo.

Comment: I was about to publish my answer than i got update that you already did. Thats correct.

Comment: The `ngModel` directive is what I missed, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you must get the value in the template reference like this

`<input [(ngModel)]="confirmationText" type='text' #myInput>
 <button [disabled]="myInput.value != 'yes'">Delete</button>`

look at my solution

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x9znsw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but without the `ngModel` directive, it doesn't work, for example, try this `<input type='text' #myInput>`

Comment: @cyberpirate92 - This answer should work because the `ngModel` directive is set in the input element. However, it involves the declaration of `confirmationText` in the component class, which is what you want to avoid.